# What is the culture neutral dateformat for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime-format

I have this question since the dawn of my programming career. Is there really a culture neutral format for datetime in sql server so that when ever I'm sending query string from a client side to the database server running sql server 2008 side having different system datetime format, and if the query contains a date converted to a string, what format would not give me an error.

Comment: @Soham: Wouldn't the timezone (for the date being sent) be required as well?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - That is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend reading Tibor Karaszi's [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes).

If you input your date/time in unseparated or ISO 8601 format, then you should be fine with any configuration.

```
Unseparated = 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss'
ISO 8601    = 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss'
```

**Update** (from comments):

If you need to enter a date only (without the time part), then you have to use the `'YYYYMMDD'` format, as `'YYYY-MM-DD'` will not work. See the linked article for an example.

Comment: For SQL Server and `DATETIME` types, you need to use either `YYYYMMDD` (**no dashes!** if you need DATE only - no time), or the format you mentioned (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`) - both work.

Comment: Yes, i mentioned both. I usually prefer the "no dashes" version. It's more concise.

Comment: Not really - you didn't mention the format if you need date only (without time). Contrary to what one could be lead to believe, `YYYY-MM-DD` would **NOT** work (while `YYYYMMDD`) does....

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid, how does one specify timezone? In that case, wouldn't UTC date format be appropriate?

Comment: The single timezone aware type in SQL Server is datetimeoffset (since 2008). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx for details.

Comment: @MicSim: If the date comes from the client (sending it to a web server), what timezone, the date would be in? i.e. lets say the client sends 20121112T16:44:00, shouldn't it specify timezone as well?

Comment: You would never just get the data that the client sends you and put it in database. You, as the recipient should have control (or at least knowledge) of what date information the client is supposed to enter/send. Then you have to parse and transform this date according to your storing schema in the database. Never use database representation for view representation (and vice versa)!

Comment: When targeting a `DATE` type (as distinct from say `DATETIME`) I would still prefer the ISO 8601 format with midnight for the time element  e.g. `CAST('2012-01-11T00:00:00' AS DATE)`. More verbose, yes, but easier to read and is Standard ;)

Comment: The EXCELLENT reference link is broken. Its new address is https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider storing your date/times in [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format.